# Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in /home/*/public_html/application/core/MY_Controller.php on line 137

Tags: php, mysql

I'am getting:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in /home/nbaxy/public_html/application/core/MY_Controller.php on line 137

MY_Controller.php:

```
<?php

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{

    private $dblabg =  array();
    public function __construct()
    {       
        parent::__construct();      


        if($this->config->item("use_database") == 1)
        {           
            $this->load->database();
            $this->load->model("dashboard/admin");                              
            $this->set_config();    
            if($this->config->item("module_user_online") == 1 )
            {       
                $this->set_online();        
            }

        }
        $this->set_lang();
        $this->clean_cache();

        if($this->router->fetch_module() == 'dashboard')
        {
            $this->__dashboard();
        }



    }
    protected function set_lang()
    {       
        if($this->config->item("user_change_lang") == "1")
        {           
            if($this->input->get("lang"))
            {               
                if(in_array($this->input->get("lang"),$this->config->item("langs_available")) || $this->config->item("use_db_language") == '1')
                {                   
                    $this->config->set_item("lang",$this->input->get("lang"));
                    $this->session->set_userdata('lang', $this->input->get("lang"));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if($this->session->userdata('lang') != '')
                {
                    $this->config->set_item("lang",$this->session->userdata('lang'));
                }
                else
                {
                    if($this->config->item("language_browser") == '1' )
                    {
                        $lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
                        $temp = $this->admin->getTable('languages',array("iso" => $lang));

                        if($temp->num_rows()>0 && $this->config->item("language_browser") == '1' && $this->router->fetch_module() != 'dashboard')
                        {
                            $d = $temp->row();
                            $this->config->set_item("lang",$d->language);
                        }
                    }                   

                }
            }           
        }
        if($this->config->item("use_db_language") == '1')
        {           
            $this->load_db_language($this->config->item("lang"));
        }
        else
            $this->lang->load($this->config->item("lang"),$this->config->item("lang"));         

    }

    public function load_db_language($lang = 'english')
    {



        $this->db->select   ('*');
        $this->db->from     ('language');
        $this->db->where    ('language', $lang);        

        $query = $this->db->get()->result();
        foreach ( $query as $row )        
        {
            $return[$row->key] = $row->text;

        }

        $this->dblabg = $return;


        $this->db->select   ('*');
        $this->db->from     ('languages');        
        $query = $this->db->get()->result();
        $return = array();
        foreach ( $query as $row )        
        {  
            $return[$row->language] = $row->language;
        }        

        $this->config->set_item("langs_available", $return);                

        unset($query,$return);
    }


    public function get_label($key)
    {
        return  $this->dblabg[$key];
    }

    protected function clean_cache()
    {
        if(exec('echo EXEC') == 'EXEC')
        {
            if($this->config->item("clean_cache") != '0')
            {               
                exec("find  ".getcwd()." -type f -name '*.cache' -mtime +".$this->config->item("clean_cache")." -exec rm {} \;");                   
            }

        }
    }

    protected function set_online()
    {
        $this->admin->setUsuarioOnline(intval($this->session->userdata('id')));
    }
    protected function set_config()
    {       

        $config     = $this->admin->getTable("settings");       
        if($config->num_rows() == 0)
        {
            show_error("No settings founds in your database, you need install this script on clean database",400);
        }
        foreach ($config->result_array() as $row)
        {

            if($row['var'] != 'use_database')
            {
                if($row['var'] == 'langs_available')
                {

                    $this->load->helper('directory');
                    $langs = directory_map('./application/language');
                    foreach ($langs as $key => $value) {
                         $temp[] = $key;                        
                    }                   
                    $row['value'] = $temp;                   
                }                               
                if($row['var'] == 'theme')
                {
                    if($_GET['skin'])
                    {
                        $row['value'] = $_GET['skin'];
                    }
                }
                if(!is_array($row['value']))
                {
                    //$row['value'] = str_ireplace('"', "'",$row['value']);
                    $row['value'] = str_ireplace('\"', '"',$row['value']);
                    $row['value'] = str_ireplace("\'", "'",$row['value']);
                    $row['value'] = html_entity_decode($row['value']);  

                }

                $this->config->set_item($row['var'], $row['value']);    


                if($this->agent->is_mobile())
                {                   
                    $this->config->set_item("theme", $this->config->item("theme_mobile"));                                                      
                }
            }

        }

        if($this->agent->is_mobile())
        {           
            if($this->config->item("mobile_redirect") != '')                
                redirect($this->config->item("mobile_redirect"), 'location', 301);
        }

        if(is_logged())
        {
            $this->config->set_item("biography_lang_temp",$this->config->item("biography_lang"));                       
            $this->config->set_item("biography_lang", $this->session->userdata('biography_lang'));                      
        }       





           $config = Array(
                'protocol' => 'smtp',
                'smtp_host' => $this->config->item("smtp_host"),
                'smtp_port' => $this->config->item("smtp_port"),
                'smtp_user' => $this->config->item("smtp_user"), // change it to yours
                'smtp_pass' => $this->config->item("smtp_pass"), // change it to yours
                'mailtype' => 'html',
                'charset' => 'utf-8',
                'wordwrap' => TRUE
        );
        $this->load->library('email',$config);  
    }

    protected function __dashboard()
    {
        if($this->config->item("use_database") == 0)
        {
            show_404(); 
        }
        if(!is_logged() && $this->router->method != 'login'  && $this->router->method != 'logout' )
        {
            redirect(base_url()."dashboard/login");
        }           
        if($this->session->userdata('is_admin') != 1 && $this->router->method != 'login')
        {
            //redirect(base_url(),"refresh");
            redirect(base_url()."dashboard/login");
        }
        else{
            if($this->session->userdata('username') == 'demo@jodacame.com' && $this->router->method != 'login')
            {
                if($this->router->method == 'website')
                {
                    $this->config->set_item("lastfm", 'lastfmdemomodeapikey');          
                }
                if($_POST || $this->router->method == 'smtp' || $this->router->method == 'license' || $this->router->method =='users'  || $this->router->method =='lyrics'  ||  $this->router->method == 'newsletter' )
                {
                    show_error("Demo Account don't have permission for this action",403);
                }

            }
            // Upgrade            
            if(file_exists("upgrade/upgrade.sql"))
            {
                $MD5 = md5_file("upgrade/upgrade.sql");
                if($this->config->item("md5updated") != $MD5)
                {
                    $sql    = file_get_contents("upgrade/upgrade.sql");
                    $sqls   = explode(";\n",$sql);
                    foreach ($sqls as $key => $value) {                             
                        if($value != '')
                        {
                            $this->db->query($value);
                            //echo $this->db->last_query()."<br>";  
                        }                       
                    }               
                    $this->db->query("UPDATE settings SET value = '$MD5' WHERE var='md5updated';");                 
                    $this->session->sess_destroy();                 
                    //echo $this->db->last_query()."<br>";
                    redirect(base_url()."dashboard/login/1");
                }               

            }

            if(file_exists("install.sql"))
            {
                $sql    = file_get_contents("install.sql");
                $sqls   = explode(";\n",$sql);
                foreach ($sqls as $key => $value) {                             
                    if($value != '')
                    {
                        $this->db->query($value);
                        //echo $this->db->last_query()."<br>";  
                    }                       
                }           
                unlink("install.sql");
                redirect(base_url()."dashboard/login/2");
            }                               



            // Check install modules



        }       

    }
}
```

Please tell me, how can i fix this?

Comment: Which is the line 137? Check always  that your query has been successful before going on.

Comment: What is the `$this->admin`? Looks like the `$this->admin->getTable()` is not returning what you expect it to return.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are calling  "$temp->num_rows()" Your Variable $temp is not a result set from a Database Query. You are calling a method that doesn't exist.  It seems you are trying to get the number of rows of data that are on the table 'languages'.  In this case you would need to execute a $SQL query.

```
Example:

// this assumes $mysqli is a successfull connection to the table 'languages'
$query = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `languages`";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

$row_cnt = $result->num_rows; //$row_cnt now equals an integer.
}
```

*Note: You need to replace $temp->numrows with if($row_cnt > 0...)